# Is there a way in asp.net core to compile only part of the code at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to build an asp.net core app that creates random matrixs.

The problem i am facing is that i will probably need to change the logic of the matrix creation at run time.

So my question is there a way to put the logic of the matrix creation in a different file so i could change that file at runtime and compile only that file.

Comment: In general "yes you can easily do it in c#, dynamics, reflection, dynamic methods, dll injections" all tools are there. But you are not describing the problem well enough for us to tell you which tool could get the job done

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Further details could help, but if you can't make your code configurable enough to avoid code changes and subsequent releases, then I'd suggest you could build a service responsible for 'matrix creation'. You could expose this service via the API.

The 'consumer' needn't care about how the matrix is being created, or even which version of the implementation it's calling, as long as the contract doesn't change.